# Replace each unique value in a sorted Pandas dataframe column with i

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a list of user IDs that are about 40 characters long. I want to replace those user IDs with a number i starting from 0 for each id in order to save space.

What I have:

```
userID      itemID
------------------
3a            r5
3a            r6
4b            r5
4c            r6
```

What I need:

```
 userID      itemID
 ------------------
 0            r5
 0            r6
 1            r5
 2            r6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [pd.factorize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
In [145]: df
Out[145]:
  userID itemID
0     3a     r5
1     3a     r6
2     4b     r5
3     4c     r6

In [146]: df.userID = pd.factorize(df.userID)[0]

In [147]: df
Out[147]:
   userID itemID
0       0     r5
1       0     r6
2       1     r5
3       2     r6
```

if your main goal is to save memory - you can categorize your column:

```
In [155]: df = pd.concat([df] * 5, ignore_index=True)

In [156]: df
Out[156]:
   userID itemID
0      3a     r5
1      3a     r6
2      4b     r5
3      4c     r6
4      3a     r5
5      3a     r6
6      4b     r5
7      4c     r6
8      3a     r5
9      3a     r6
10     4b     r5
11     4c     r6
12     3a     r5
13     3a     r6
14     4b     r5
15     4c     r6
16     3a     r5
17     3a     r6
18     4b     r5
19     4c     r6

In [157]: df.memory_usage()
Out[157]:
Index      80
userID    160
itemID    160
dtype: int64
```

categorizing `userID`:

```
In [158]: df.userID = df.userID.astype('category')

In [159]: df.memory_usage()
Out[159]:
Index      80
userID     44    # <------------ NOTE:
itemID    160
dtype: int64

In [160]: df
Out[160]:
   userID itemID
0      3a     r5
1      3a     r6
2      4b     r5
3      4c     r6
4      3a     r5
5      3a     r6
6      4b     r5
7      4c     r6
8      3a     r5
9      3a     r6
10     4b     r5
11     4c     r6
12     3a     r5
13     3a     r6
14     4b     r5
15     4c     r6
16     3a     r5
17     3a     r6
18     4b     r5
19     4c     r6

In [161]: df.dtypes
Out[161]:
userID    category
itemID      object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks that tip will be used in the future! In this case, I'm preprocessing the data using pandas then another program will use the data but it needs to be in that format so I don't know that categorizing will help.

Comment: @mmera, the first solution will give you integers - isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry! Yes the first example was exactly what I needed. I meant the categorizing part was what I won't be using this time but is a good tip nonetheless.

Comment: @mmera, glad i could help :)